# Mule: dataweave in mule version 3.7.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

Which component of DataWeave should I use to support DataWeave coding in Mule server 3.7.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but you'd want to use the "Transform Message" component to utilize DataWeave.  You can also find it by searching for "datamapper" or "dataweave" in the Mule Palette.

However, keep in mind you'll need a newer version of Studio to use DataWeave, and a server with a Mule 3.7 Enterprise license.

Hope that helps,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

'in the 3.7 anypoint studio, "Transform Message" component is used for DataWeave transformations.

Answer (score 0):

In `Mule 3.7` search `DataWeave` in the palette section and you will get `Transform Message`. Just drag and drop this to use `DataWeave`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message transform form mule pallet.
the syntax of message tranform is

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Message Transform">
        <dw:set-payload resource="classpath:dwlfile.dwl"/>
```

paste your dwl file under resource folder

Answer (score 0):

you can use Transform Message component, can be find from mule pallete. data weave is available from 3.7 version onwards

Answer (score 0):

Transform Message component is used fro DataWeave

Comment: This is more or less a comment not an answer.

Comment: Is this just repeating all the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Transform message component from mule pallete for DataWeave for Mule 3.7

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't believe that your answer adds something that has not been answered before. Please refrain from posting unnecessary answers.

Answer (score 0):

From  Mule 3.5 onwords no more Datamapper in use. You should go with Transform weave component.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/transform-message-component-concept-studio

you can migrate the old code of datamapper to transform weave if you want please go through this mule doc for this